# Как корректно ограничить область Drag'n'Drop?

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Есть маленький `div` внутри большого `div`. Через JS применен Drag'n'Drop к малому `div`. Необходимо ограничить область перемещения меньшего блока.

[Попытка реализации](https://jsfiddle.net/8tfgwpL7/)

Но если попробовать резко переместить белый блок влево или вверх, то он "залипнет" недалеко от границы. Как это исправить?

```js
var small = document.getElementById('small');
small.onmousedown = function(e) {
  move(e);

  function move(e) {
    if (e.pageX > 0) {
      small.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
    }
    if (e.pageY > 0) {
      small.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
    }
  }
  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    move(e);
  }
  small.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    small.onmouseup = null
  }
}
```

```css
#big {
  width: 12cm;
  height: 12cm;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

#small {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.75cm;
  top: 0.75cm;
  width: 4cm;
  height: 4cm;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="big">
  <div id="small"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, надо иметь возможность перенести блок выше и левее края документа или всё-таки ограничить перемещение внутри серого блока?

Comment: @br3t Ограничить перемещение внутри. И чтоб при перемещении указателя мыши за края большого блока меньший `div` был вплотную с границей.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для правильного позиционирования `small` необходимо рассчитать координаты, за которые нельзя этот `small` выпускать. Т.е. мы имеем четыре границы: верхнюю, нижнюю, левую, правую.

Для наглядности в примере добавлены отступы у `big` и фон у `body`.

```js
var small = document.getElementById('small');
var big = document.getElementById('big');
//* флаг перетаскивания
var isDrag = false;
//* ограничения, за которые нельзя вытащить small
var limits = {
  top: big.offsetTop,
  right: big.offsetWidth + big.offsetLeft - small.offsetWidth,
  bottom: big.offsetHeight + big.offsetTop - small.offsetHeight,
  left: big.offsetLeft
};

//* вкл/выкл режим перетаскивания
small.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDrag = true;
}
document.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrag = false;
}
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (isDrag) {
    move(e);
  }
}

//* вычисление координат
function move(e) {
  var newLocation = {
    x: limits.left,
    y: limits.top
  };
  if (e.pageX > limits.right) {
    newLocation.x = limits.right;
  } else if (e.pageX > limits.left) {
    newLocation.x = e.pageX;
  }
  if (e.pageY > limits.bottom) {
    newLocation.y = limits.bottom;
  } else if (e.pageY > limits.top) {
    newLocation.y = e.pageY;
  }
  relocate(newLocation);
}

//* размещение small
function relocate(newLocation) {
  small.style.left = newLocation.x + 'px';
  small.style.top = newLocation.y + 'px';
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #EEF;
}
#big {
  width: 12cm;
  height: 12cm;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  margin: 2cm;
}
#small {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2.75cm;
  top: 2.75cm;
  width: 4cm;
  height: 4cm;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="big">
  <div id="small"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Андрей, не знаю, какая конкретно у вас задача стоит, но я бы заморочился ещё сохранением позиции курсора внутри `small` и работал бы с относительными координатами `small` внутри `big`.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, но это уже возможно сделать самостоятельно, пользуясь лишь справочником.

Comment: [@br3t](/users/221753/br3t), спасибо за быстрый и понятный ответ!

Comment: не нашел в справочнике, подскажи, если не сложно, как сохранить позиционирование

Comment: @ДмитрийМаслов, см нестандартный https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/layerX и более стандартный https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX

Comment: Если есть уже готовый пример, буду благодарен